# How to find this integration?

Tags: integration

Can some please help me to find this integral.

$\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}x^{-2\beta}\text{d}x$

Is there any closed-form solution. Approximation is welcome..

Comment: Is $\beta$ real, natural, or complex?

Comment: Seems like some variant of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @Axoren, it is a  real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = -2\beta + 1$. Then ($y = tx,dy = t\,dx$)
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} x^{-2\beta} dx
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} x^{\alpha - 1} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{t} \int_0^\infty e^{-y} t^{-\alpha+1} y^{\alpha - 1} dy \\
&= t^{-\alpha} \int_0^\infty e^{-y} y^{\alpha - 1} dy \\
&= t^{-\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha) = t^{2\beta - 1} \Gamma(-2\beta + 1)
\end{align*}$$
There are certain restrictions on $t$ and $\beta$ though.

Comment: Would you please explain the restrictions in details..

Comment: @Dimitrios Obviously $t \neq 0$ for negative $2\beta - 1$. Also, $-2\beta + 1$ cannot evaluate to a nonpositive integer.

Comment: The integral will only converge at zero if $\Re(\beta)<\frac{1}{2}$.